# Nas introcuded creating and xts object based on POSIXct object in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, xts, posixct

I am trying to generate an xts objet based on intraday data of 5 min spam. The problem comes when transforming the date-time into a POSIXct object. By doing it, it activates the daylight saving time, and my format changes. When creating the object the differences in format create NAs, and my cts object is not generated.

## I read the data from my csv file

data = fread("….csv", header = T,  sep = ",")

## Take the date-time and store it in one variable

time <- data[,1]

## This is how my dates look like

data[,1]

[844] "03.01.2019 22:15:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 22:20:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 22:25:00.000 GMT+0100"
[847] "03.01.2019 22:30:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 22:35:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 22:40:00.000 GMT+0100"
[850] "03.01.2019 22:45:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 22:50:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 22:55:00.000 GMT+0100"
[853] "03.01.2019 23:00:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:05:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:10:00.000 GMT+0100"
[856] "03.01.2019 23:15:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:20:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:25:00.000 GMT+0100"
[859] "03.01.2019 23:30:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:35:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:40:00.000 GMT+0100"
[862] "03.01.2019 23:45:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:50:00.000 GMT+0100" "03.01.2019 23:55:00.000 GMT+0100"
[865] "04.01.2019 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:05:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:10:00.000 GMT+0100"
[868] "04.01.2019 00:15:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:20:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:25:00.000 GMT+0100"
[871] "04.01.2019 00:30:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:35:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:40:00.000 GMT+0100"
[874] "04.01.2019 00:45:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:50:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 00:55:00.000 GMT+0100"
[877] "04.01.2019 01:00:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 01:05:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 01:10:00.000 GMT+0100"
[880] "04.01.2019 01:15:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 01:20:00.000 GMT+0100" "04.01.2019 01:25:00.000 GMT+0100"

## I create the new POSIX variable

x2 <- as.POSIXct(time, format='%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S')

## my new variable looks like this (you can see the timezone has changed from April)

x2

[845] "2019-03-01 22:20:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 22:25:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 22:30:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 22:35:00 CET"
[849] "2019-03-01 22:40:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 22:45:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 22:50:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 22:55:00 CET"
[853] "2019-03-01 23:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:05:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:10:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:15:00 CET"
[857] "2019-03-01 23:20:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:25:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:30:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:35:00 CET"
[861] "2019-03-01 23:40:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:45:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:50:00 CET"  "2019-03-01 23:55:00 CET"
[865] "2019-04-01 00:00:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:05:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:10:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:15:00 CEST"
[869] "2019-04-01 00:20:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:25:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:30:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:35:00 CEST"
[873] "2019-04-01 00:40:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:45:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:50:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 00:55:00 CEST"
[877] "2019-04-01 01:00:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 01:05:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 01:10:00 CEST" "2019-04-01 01:15:00 CEST"
[881] "2019-04-01 01:20:00 CEST"

## Then I create the xts but the error saying that NAs are generated appears

data.xts <- xts(data[,2], order.by = x2)

**Error in xts(data[, 2], order.by = x2) :
'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'**

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Edit your post to include `dput(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry after 6 hours I realised my mistake. In this step, this is correct:

x2 <- as.POSIXct(time, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

**NOT**

x2 <- as.POSIXct(time, format='%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S')